# Parse JSON answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a response and I need the value of one parameter and I don't know how to parse it.

This is the response. I just need a hint to find out how to extract the data from this response and save it to one variable.

Then the next step is to show it, to prove that it gave me the activation code.

```
{"status":"created","statusCode":"0001","message":{"type":"success","text":"\xd8\xab\xd8\xa8\xd8\xaa\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85 \xd9\x85\xd9\x88\xd9\x81\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xd8\xaa \xd8\xa2\xd9\x85\xdb\x8c\xd8\xb2 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf"},"error":[],"data":{"user":{"uuid":"f0dd5bee-2228-42a2-a832-ca577002496d","username":"droppp459","phoneNumber":"09443757689","activationCode":"73821"}}}'
```

And this is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpath

# Api
url = "http://dropp.dlinkddns.com:5000/api/users/register/complete"


def test_new_user():
    # ReadFile
    file = open("/Users/amirmarezloo/Downloads/Js.json")
    json_input=file.read()
    request_json=json.loads(json_input)
    #Post
    response=requests.post(url,request_json)
    #Response
    assert response.status_code==201
    #Header
    print(response.headers.get("Content-Type"))
    #Parse
    response_json=json.loads(response.text)
    #Pick
    Active=jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json,'activationCode')
    print(response.content)
```

In this case, I would like to print on screen `73821` which is the activation code given in the response.

Comment: Fix grammar and intent.

Comment: I reformated the question, fixed some grammar errors and use some other words to describe your problem. If you read the guidelines you will see that 'please help/hi everyone/I am a beginner', are not really required, since they are not helpful to know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse from jsonpath_ng ( pip install jsonpath-ng )

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse

jsonpathExp = parse("$..[*].activationCode")
match = jsonpathExp.find(response_json)

for item in match:
    print(item.value,"\n")
```

Parsing contexts:
**$** indicates **the root object**
**.** indicates **next level**
***** indicates **any field**
**[n]** indicates **list index**